# Is there a way to "unset" options in uWSGI config files?

Tags: uwsgi

Let's say my config (`uwsgi.ini`) looks like:

```
# can run just by uwsgi uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi]
# put all common elements here (can be over-ridden)
http = :8090
wsgi-file = ./test.py
master = 1
processes = 4
threads = 2
#uid=www-data
#gid=www-data

# run via: uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini:dev
[dev]
ini=:uwsgi
py-autoreload = 2 

# run via: uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini:prod
[prod]
ini=:uwsgi

[dev-nginx]
ini=:uwsgi
socket= :8001
py-autoreload = 2 

[prod-nginx]
ini=:uwsgi
socket= :8001
```

If I wanted to use uWSGI behind Nginx, I could run via `uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini:prod-nginx`, but I'd want to *unset* the `http = :8090` part, that was set in the main `[uwsgi]` section.

Is there a way to *unset* this in the `[prod-nginx]` section, rather than duplicating everything everywhere, and not including one part inside another?